# Unnesting(?) a json string into columns and rows and duplicating down the order ids

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I extract the "product_id" into another column and row? I want it to look like the expected output screenshot. I'm not very experienced in json related functions so I tried using a json_extract_scalar but I think that doesn't deal with arrays?

**Item Cell I want to extract into multiple cells**

```
[{"product_id":"18741173","quantity":25,"price":7.9900000000000002,"price_raw":7.9900000000000002},
{"product_id":"17090192","quantity":3,"price":6.9900000000000002,"price_raw":6.9900000000000002},
{"product_id":"16152704","quantity":3,"price":6.9900000000000002,"price_raw":6.9900000000000002}]
```

[Example data with order ID and purchase details in "items"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAXgJ.png)
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1cT7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select orderId, json_value(item, '$.product_id') product_id,
  round(cast(json_value(item, '$.price_raw') as float64), 2) price
from your_table, unnest(json_query_array(items)) item
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]